# How to install and use a new .bst?

Tags: bibtex

I want to use the PNAS bibliography style [available here](https://www.pnas.org/page/authors/latex) in a plain, vanilla article (not the PNAS article).

I have saved the pnas2016.bst file in the same directory as the rest of the .tex files, but bibTeX cannot seem to find and use the pnas2016.bst citation style.

Additionally, I have placed the pnas2016.bst file in "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\pnas2016.bst"

MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimum Working Example}
\author{Aw~Thor\thanks{A. Thor is with the ...}}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~11, No.~12, August~2016}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of Minimum example for stack exchange}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Why won't this .bst work?\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
bibtex, LaTeX, PNAS bibliography style
\end{IEEEkeywords}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{B}{ibliography} styles are giving me a headache \cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}.

\section*{Acknowledgments}
The authors would like to thank whoever can help them fix this problem.

% references section
%\newpage
%\footnotesize{
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\bibliographystyle{pnas2016}
%}
\end{document}
```

Note that while this creates the citation, it's not in PNAS style - notably, not in the text, where it should show round parentheses instead of square brackets.

What am I doing wrong?

Log File:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.25)  20 SEP 2019 17:02
entering extended mode
**./MWE.tex
(MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

("C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ieeetran\IEEEtran.
cls"
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen102
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen103
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen104
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count80
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count81
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count82
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 503.

("C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1ptm.fd"
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen105
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen106
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen107
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen108
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen109
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen110
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen111
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen112
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen113
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen114
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen115
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen116
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen117
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen118
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen119
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip41
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip42
\belowcaptionskip=\skip43
\c@figure=\count88
\c@table=\count89
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count90
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count91
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count92
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen120
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen121
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen122
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen123
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count93
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box27
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen124
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen125
\c@IEEEbiography=\count94
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box28
) (MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

-- Lines per column: 58 (exact).
(MWE.bbl)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 33.
 [1{C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}



] (MWE.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1045 strings out of 492897
 19367 string characters out of 3123754
 80950 words of memory out of 3000000
 5027 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 36172 words of font info for 66 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 28i,7n,19p,201b,210s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/
base/8r.enc}<C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/t
imes/utmb8a.pfb><C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/u
rw/times/utmbi8a.pfb><C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/ty
pe1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on MWE.pdf (1 page, 40999 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: The linked file is called `pnas-new.bst` when you download it. Did you rename it to `pnas2016.bst`? And do you have `\bibliographystyle{pnas2016}` in your source document?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it, and I have \bibliographystyle{pnas2016} in the source. The error I get is: I couldn't open style file pnas2016.bst
---line 2 of file bib-database.aux
 : \bibstyle{pnas2016
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

Comment: Have you deleted all the `.aux` files, and tried it again?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I've done that.

Comment: Having exhausted the simple explanations, can you edit your question to show a minimal document that can reproduce the problem? And the `.blg` file?  What you're doing should work.

Comment: Added MWE, but no .blg. I don't know a good way to share a .blg file. Any tips?

Comment: The `.blg` file shouldn't be too long for this document, but just the first 5 or so lines should be fine.

Comment: Place `\bibliographystyle{pnas2016}` **prior** to the `\bibliography` invocation!

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @AlanMunn is this the log information you requested? The .blg file doesn't contain anything I can share. This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.25)  20 SEP 2019 17:02
entering extended mode
**./MWE.tex
(MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ieeetran\IEEEtran.
cls"
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/